# How to return a value using the Puppeteer library to scrape dynamic web pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, puppeteer, cheerio

I am using cheerio.js and puppeteer.js following this [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3) to try to do some basic web scraping. I'm not following exactly as the tutorial as I am trying to write it on the server side with the idea of having my backend handle all the scraping and then in the future pass that data to a front end.

As it is written now, I am getting

`[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
 [nodemon] starting node server.js
 Your app is listening on port 8080
 [Function]`

Looks like the `dynamicScraper` is returning `[Function]` when I would expect it to be the html like in the tutorial?

Main server.js file

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const cheerio = require('./potusScraper');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
    })
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let { scraper, dynamicScraper } = cheerio;
    //dynamicScraper should return html as a string?
    dynamicScraper()
        .then(html => {
            res.send(html);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}`);
});
```

potusScraper.js file

```
'use strict';

const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States';
const url2 = 'https://www.reddit.com';



const cheerio = {
    scraper: function() {
        return rp(url)
            .then(html => {
                const wikiUrls=[];
                for (let i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
                    wikiUrls.push($('big > a', html)[i].attribs.href);
                }
                return(wikiUrls);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
    dynamicScraper: function() {
       return puppeteer //doesn't look like this works?
            .launch()
            .then(browser => {
                return browser.newPage();
            })
            .then(page => {
                return page.goto(url2)
                    .then(() => {return page.content});
            })
            .then(html => {
                console.log(html);
                return(html);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

}

module.exports = cheerio;
```

Comment: [`page.content`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.13.0&show=api-pagecontent) is a method: `function(): Promise<string>`

Comment: Dang, seriously. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @customcommander Just noticed your comment after posting an answer. If you want to write an answer yourself, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Up to you I don’t mind. I didn’t think it needed a formal answer as this clearly is a developer typo.  I found some guidance about answers found in comments https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/1244884. Basically you can post a community answer when your answer is based on non-own comments leading to a resolution.

Comment: @customcommander Just did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the [`page.content`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecontent) function in this code lines instead of calling it:

```js
            .then(page => {
                return page.goto(url2)
                    .then(() => {return page.content});
            })
```

The third line should look like this:

```js
                    .then(() => {return page.content()});
```

In addition, you could simplify your code by using a concise arrow function:

```js
                    .then(() => page.content());
```